# Is there a Matplotlib equivalent to the Borland C command putpixel?

Tags: python, linux, windows, matplotlib, plot

I am interested in porting some of my old fractal imaging programs over from Borland C to python.  In Borland C, the putpixel command would place a specified color pixel within a rasterized graphical field.  Is there a simple way to do this in matplotlib?

Comment: Matplotlib does not really work with pixels. Are you sure you don't want to use `PIL`, the image library of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this I discovered that there is a putpixel command in PIL (Python Imaging Library), which has tools for dealing with pixel oriented graphics.  Matplotlib can also do the job as suggested by the answer above.

Comment: I've used pillow to generate synthetic star maps, as well as colored pixel arrays to use in developing multilayer images using GIMP or Photoshop.  I find the scripting easier to do than in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer depends on what you're trying to do here. matplotlib has a lot of utilities for working with representing image data, [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/images.html) might give a good starting point for getting familiar with matplotlib's workflow. You can directly edit the values of the numpy array that you're using matplotlib to visualize, but matplotlib doesn't give you access to the data that you're rendering.

I imagine that you already have written some colormap and other rendering tools tools, but to get an idea of what matplotlib might have built in, I recommend looking at this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/showcase/mandelbrot.html). It's a simple Mandelbrot, escape time, but it makes use of nonlinear colormapping and shading.

In my experience, I've normally computed the fractal as a 2D numpy array, and then allowed matplotlib to handle the coloring, and scaling of the final output image. Matplotlib doesn't work like the canvas experience it sounds like you're used to using. I'd recommend filling a numpy array with the desired pixel values as you've computed them, and then sending that array off to matplotlib to be rendered.